# How can you tell if your Kodak D76 developer cannot be used anymore?

Tags: film, developing, kodak, chemicals, development

I just constructed my stock D76 developer and am beginning to use it.

How can I check when it cannot be used anymore for further development?

Comment: It will typically turn dark brown in colour and have a strong odour. Avoid using aggressive agitation (which will introduce air into solution) to dissolve the powder when making your stock solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way of knowing if it is exhausted (you could process small test lengths of film perhaps).  Rather, I would follow [Kodak's guidelines](https://imaging.kodakalaris.com/sites/prod/files/files/resources/j78.pdf) (PDF link) for it, probably being rather conservative about both how long it keeps and how much film to process: film is *much* more expensive than dev, and exposed film is irreplaceable, so wasting a little dev by under-using it is a lot safer than possibly ruining film.